# How to print page in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jzaefferer.github.com/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<?php $this->load->view('includes/header'); ?>

<div class="container-fluid" style=" min-height: 500px; " >
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <?php $this->load->view('includes/sidebar'); ?>
    <?php $this->load->view($main_content); ?>
  </div>
</div>

<form id="print" method="post" action="<?php echo base_url().'index.php/'; ?>printdocument/print_a_document">
     <div class="controls">
      <input style="width: 185px;" id="print_button" type="submit" value="Print">
      <input type="hidden" name="print_template" value="<?php echo $main_content; ?>">
      <input type="hidden" name="records" value="<?php echo $records; ?>">
      <input type="hidden" name="print_template" value="<?php echo $main_content; ?>">
    </div>
</form>
```

then in controller

```
class Printdocument extends CI_Controller{

    function print_a_document()
    {
        $data['main_content'] = $this->input->post('print_template');
        $data['records'] = $this->input->post('records');
        $this->load->view('includes/print_template', $data);
    }
}
```

I need to pass records How to pass them?

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Array to string conversion

Filename: includes/template_print.php

Line Number: 16

Array">

Comment: what do u get in `$main_content`

Comment: @ tereško, HamZa, ircmaxell, Ocramius, Mr. Alien Can you reopen it I have edited question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is you are trying to assign a string to a array. It to be noted you doing it for a array and not a array element. Thus the problem what your are facing. Post a array of the data you want to print and save it to `$data` array.

Comment: i don't see any difference between the question and your answer... plus... you have created an extraa variable which is not needed at all..

Comment: Can i know what are you posting in print_template?

Comment: print_template do not contain header, footer, and sidebar. It has only main body content.

Answer (score 0):

You should not explicitly declare index.php in form submitting

```
action="<?php echo base_url().'index.php/'; ?>printdocument/print_a_document">
```

index.php is implicitly added by the CI frmaework.

```
action="<?php echo base_url().'printdocument/print_a_document'; ?>">
```

can you edit your code as above and check.?